# Update a header based on live entry into a text field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a header caption that starts as "Placeholder". Then I have three field; First name, last name and Title. I want to update and then append that caption as the user types into those three fields.

So if someone enters the name, "Steven" into the first name field, the caption should update from placeholder to Steven.

```
Private Sub First_Name_AfterUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.provider_label.Caption = Me.First_Name.Value
End Sub
```

I thought this code would work but it doesn't. Almost seems too simple. I'm writing it in VBA in Microsoft Access on a form.

Comment: What does "doesn't" mean - error message, wrong results, nothing happens? Why do you even need to do this? Rather bizarre design. Why should the label duplicate the data? Why not just a generic label like "First Name".

Comment: @June7 It's someone else's design that I'm assisting with. The Placeholder caption isn't updating when the text fields are changed. The caption needs to be a concatenation of First, Last name and title so we can't do a generic label. Specifically because the form is intended to support adding a new customer, whose attributes are defined on the same form.

Comment: `AfterUpdate()` doesn't have the `Cancel` parameter. Something is very off here.

Comment: Have you placed the event into the AfterUpdate property of the first_name control.

Comment: Still bizarre. This means changing the label caption after each data element is input. Duplicates what is already displayed in each input control. Instead of VBA, could just have a textbox with expression that concatenates the data elements. Set the textbox as TabStop No. You say this is a 'header' caption - header for what? Or is this just a detached label on a form?

Comment: @june7, I think OP is using a label that is separate from the three individual labels he's updating.

Comment: @June7 That's not really possible because the individual may not have a title, or they may only have a last name and title, etc. So we need to detect which fields aren't null and then concatenate them to the text box header. This needs to be handled differently when defining a new individual, since all text fields will be blank initially.

Comment: Entirely possible. The Nulls can be handled in the expression.

Answer (score 2):

Non-VBA solution using expression in textbox ControlSource:

`= IIf([Last Name] & [First Name] & [Title] & "" = "", "Placeholder", [Last Name] & IIf(IsNull([Last Name]),"",", ") + [First Name] & " - " + [Title])`

or

`= IIf([Last Name] & [First Name] & [Title] & "" = "", "Placeholder", Nz([Last Name], "No LN") & ", " & Nz([First Name], "No FN") & " - " & Nz([Title], "No Title))`

Comment: Was just going to comment:  `NZ(Me!first_name,"") & " " & NZ(me!last_name,"") & " " & NZ(me!Title,"")`   (or forms!control instead of me! if you're using absolute reference)

Comment: This works! It's not optimal since there's a comma regardless of whether last name is entered or not, but it will suffice.

Comment: Revised first expression to deal with the orphan comma.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested and no issue.   Is your first_name a text box?

```
Private Sub ProviderUpdate()
    Me!provider_label.Caption = Me!first_name & " " & me!last_name & " " & me!Title
End Sub
```

Then in each individual text_box, set the event procedure to call the ProviderUpdate sub.

Comment: Suggest using dot (.) instead of bang (!) when referencing objects and controls to get intellisense tips.

Comment: what's intellisense?

Comment: Intellisense is feature in VBA (and other programming platforms as well) that provides popup help tips as you type code. The dot (.) will trigger intellisense popups, bang (!) will not. In Access 2010, intellisense was expanded to the Expression Builder, so you can see what arguments your expression requires. However, in Access objects (query, form, report) design, the bang works there to give popup help.

Comment: Ah, I actually just read up on it a bit.  I like the bang as I've always used it to refer to that collection member and dots before the properties.  I think it's an Access thing, as I've seen the notation change outside of Access - but seems like it's widely discussed.

Comment: The dot will list control names so can be helpful in typing control names in code as well as their properties.